# Eclipse (bug ?) + Bitbucket : Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh, key, bitbucket

I know the question has already been asked, but it is a failure.

The facts:

- I use Windows 7, Eclipse and **Bitbucket**
- I can't push to Bitbucket. There is Permission denied (publickey).
- When I use TortoiseGit in the folder, there is no problem : **My key (private and public) are OK** and the content is pushed.

I think that my Eclipse is properly configured : my private key is in the configuration (SSH2...) and it is the same as the test with TortoiseGit.

Conclusion : Eclipse is it bugged ?
Do you have any solution ?

I tried many things but without success.

Thx for your help !

Comment: Which version of Eclipse and Egit are you using?

Comment: please try uploading another key. there seem to be a private key mismatch.

Comment: I have already try with other key... without success

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.